# Java Jar Release Naming Conventions

Tags: java, jar, build, naming-conventions, publish

What are all the standard naming conventions for Java Releases?

For example I frequently see suffixes like the following

> 5.0.0-RC1
>
> 5.0.0-M4

In this case I know RC1 stands for "release candidate 1", but I don't know what M4 stands for.  So what are all the popular suffixes, what do they literal stand for, and when should they be used?

Answer (score 2):

M usually stands for "Milestone". A JAR can typically have several milestones before a Release Candidate (rc, as you noted) is reached, and then you can have several of those too. Under this naming convention that actual release will usually be suffixed with -GA (General Availability).